# How to add more lines in cells of Table View?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cells

I made an app with `Table View` and I put some cells, but in Cells there is only one line of text, How can I use more lines ?

> This is how it looks.
>   [image]
>
> This is how is required to be.
>    [image]

And this is code that I used:

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class DuasViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let tableList:[String] = ["Name", "Surname", "Date of Birth", "Place of Birth"]


@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    myTableView.reloadData()


    func allowMultipleLines(tableViewCell:UITableViewCell) {
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 10
        tableViewCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    var returnValue = 0

    returnValue = tableList.count

    return returnValue
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCells", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    myCell.textLabel!.text = tableList[indexPath.row]
    return myCell
}  
}
```

So how I'm gonna add more two lines, and Lines needs to be different, for ex: `Name, Stevens, Steve`. `Surname, My Surname Is, Jobs`. `Date of Birth, My Date of birth is, 01/01/2016.`

Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `numberOfLines` property of `UILabel` defaults to 1, set it to 0 to allow unlimited lines.

So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you'd have

`myCell.textLabel!.numberOfLabels = 0`

If you want `Surname, My Surname Is, Jobs` to be in different lines, you have to use a line break, which is `\n`. Your string would look like this `Surname\nMy Surname Is\nJobs`

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: If you want `Surname, My Surname Is, Jobs` to be in different lines, you have to use a line break, which is `\n`. Your string would look like this `Surname\nMy Surname Is\nJobs`

Comment: Bro, do you know how can I change size of cells, I mean some cells to be with 3 lines some with 6-7+. I have to change size in main.Storyboard and it is changing to every cell, so after this UX doesn't look verywell. To be clear, cells to be with different sizes, some higher some not.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez   Your solution works only for the first 2 rows, after adding more than 2 rows. it shows `...` instead of displaying the content in the 3rd row in the cell. `cell.textLabel?.text = "Booking# " + booking.BookingNumber + "\n" + booking.DateAndTime + "\n" + booking.PostCode`.  [Please see picture] (http://imgur.com/a/daECy) . I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1

Comment: @bibscy use a custom cell.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez   I am using a custom cell, but I get the same result with ... and the 3rd line missing . [Please see picture](http://imgur.com/a/QUI8s)

Comment: @bibscy I don't know what to tell you, I can't fix your problem in the comments section of a 10-month old answer. My guess is your cell size is too small to fit the label but you should either find help somewhere else or make your own question.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez    In viewDidLoad, I set the row height like this and it works.      `//Set the estimatedRowHeight of your table view
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
        // Set the rowHeight of your table view to UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Answer (score 1):

For new iOS 8 there is a new way to make this simple.

There is new a parameter that calculates your cell height with respect of your auto layout constraints. This is UITableViewAutomaticDimension. You can use it in the viewWillAppear method of your view controller.

Objective C:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0; // for example. Set your average height 
  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Swift:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70 // for example. Set your average height 
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Work nice and as you want at your example. As for me, I add height things in viewDidLoad and left in viewWillAppear only reloadData(). There is also useful source.

From documentation: The default value of rowHeight is UITableViewAutomaticDimension. I leave the code as it is, for now, but keep in mind that you don't need to set row height in iOS 8+.